# Installation did not succeed

Tags: android-studio, installation, android-manifest

I accidentally changed something in the manifests file I deleted a paragraph that had meta_Data in it and had something with respurce.
I can't recover it, so Android Studio doesn't run the app on the phone. I think that's why.
If there is another reason or solution for someone I would be happy.
Thank you .

this error :

```
Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION Installation failed due to: 'null'

    > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
    > xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >     package="com.lee.app1_new">
    > 
    >     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    >     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    > 
    >     <application
    >         android:allowBackup="true"
    >         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    >         android:label="@string/app_name"
    >         android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    >         android:supportsRtl="true"
    >         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    > 
    > 
    >         <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    >             <intent-filter>
    >                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    > 
    >                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    >             </intent-filter>
    >         </activity>
    >         <activity android:name=".newRecipe" />
    >         <activity android:name=".category" />
    >         <activity android:name=".recipe_cake" />
    >         <activity android:name=".full_recipe_cake" />
    >         <activity android:name=".add_recipe" />
    >         <activity android:name=".my_recipes" />
    >     </ap

    plication>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: improved formating

Answer (score 0):

Try this manifest file your  was misplaced

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lee.app1_new">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".newRecipe" />
        <activity android:name=".category" />
        <activity android:name=".recipe_cake" />
        <activity android:name=".full_recipe_cake" />
        <activity android:name=".add_recipe" />
        <activity android:name=".my_recipes" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```